# Datatable not rendering correctly after AJAX update from partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery datatable which is in partial view that is loaded in my page using AJAX. After initial load it displays correctly as you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C0ZV.png). However, after an update from a partial view it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxRM7.png). Why is this happening?

The `OnSuccess` function of my AJAX call is:

```
function CatagoryAddOnSucess() {
       var catagorytable = $("#catagorytable");
       catagorytable.dataTable({ "bDestroy": true }).fnDraw();
}
```

Comment: Check your markup, maybe you pasted partial view wrongly.

Comment: if the markup is wrong than it should not render correctly in first place as is in first image.